# What are some alternative words for an item that casts magic spells?

Tags: synonyms, terminology, vocabulary

I am designing a video game set in a medieval fantasy world, and in the game, there is a chance of receiving a random weapon. For melee weapons, I currently have around 20 different weapons, such as sword, axe, longsword, hammer, etc. For ranged weapons I have slightly less, but still quite a few, eg: bow, longbow, crossbow, sling, etc. I ran into trouble trying to think of magical weapons though, and I currently have 4; wand, staff, rod, and sceptre. I need your help to find more, preferably up to 10 synonyms of what I've already listed.

Just to clarify: certain objects are primarily used just for casting magic. I already have enchanted melee weapons, for the melee characters to use, I'm looking for weapons that the mage/wizard style character could use.

Comment: You mean you need other people to think of more.

Comment: True. Edited to reflect the fact that **I** can't think of any more.

Comment: StackExchanges are a little leery of list questions, but this only needs 7 items or so. So some I've seen are: [rod, claw,](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Heretic_weapons) [bolt, book/tome,](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Magic) and [orbs](http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Orb_%28equipment_type%29). Hope these help!

Comment: This could be easily answered by looking for a list of weapons, such as on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Weapons

Comment: Didn't Tolkien come up with something?

Comment: @curiousdannii The Wikipedia page only featured weapons like swords, guns, and bows, not magical weapons.

Comment: @edwin-ashworth As for Tolkien, I wouldn't know, I haven't read LOTR.

Comment: @Bretsky And how exactly is an staff or sceptre magical? Just put the word 'fire' or 'ghoul' in front of any word and it's instantly magical.

Comment: @curiousdannii Certain objects are primarily used just for magic. I already have enchanted melee weapons for the melee characters to use, I'm looking for weapons that the mage/wizard style character could use. Putting fire in front of a sword and making a fire sword is part of the game, but a fire sword (or any other enchanted sword) is a melee weapon, not a weapon a wizard would use.

Comment: @Bretsky They could literally use anything. They could cast a spell from a magical teapot if you chose so. I recommend that you [edit] this question to instead ask "for objects which are used for casting magic" rather than magical weapons.

Comment: I think Dumbo had a magic feather.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a question about what objects are symbolically associated with expressing magic in pop culture, not with English Language and Usage. I'll flag it.

Comment: @user867 No, it is a question about synonyms for wand, staff, etc. The only synonyms I could find in a thesaurus were related to the physical object of the item, not the magical part, i.e. treating stick or twig as wand synonyms

Comment: @Bretsky You should edit that into your question, then; As written, you're asking for *any* tools that could be used for magic, not just synonyms for wand. Dreamcatchers, for instance. Or throwing bones, or beads, or wax tablets, or books, or... Well, there's thousands of tools that could be used for magic, really.

Comment: Question belongs on the [RPG stack exchange](http://rpg.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @HotLicks Uh, no it doesn't. RPG stack exchange is about the rules and playing of already established tabletop RPGs, whereas my question is about vocabulary for making my own, new, computer game.

Comment: Well, then, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latin any good?
Baculum is a staff
Falco is a staff with a head.
Virgula is a wand
Amphibolum is a big wrap-around garment  (it also mean a pun, though)
The National Archives UK site has a good vocab of Medieval Latin.

In case you are interested:
Oxford, Corpus Christi Manuscript 122 contains a board game invented about 900; and copied there 100 years later. Google Oxford manuscripts. Find Corpus Christi 122 then turn to the page called f.5 v

O.K. Offensive magic: staff, thunderbolt, curse, 
Defensive: elixir, pentangle, charm, crystal, opoponax, tincture.

Comment: Some of those might work, but I'd like things that most people would know, so nothing too obscure.